Using AngularJS tags-input, placeholder text is getting hidden
tags-input long placeholder text is getting hidden,
I have tried using the 
 but it seems working in the browser, but in the UI, it still shows the same, Is there any other way. I have tried to override the custom classes ::placeholder this is not working. I'm not able to select the placeholder.

but in the UI, it is still shows the same 
